# Calculating running amounts with uneven number of dates

Tags: r, date, tidyverse, runner

I have a table full of dates and reply-to times for technical support tickets, and I'd like to calculate a running rate to find the average reply time over the previous *n* number of days. The data is in the following format.

| Dates | Reply Time | Ticket ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-02 | 341 | 1 |
| 2024-01-02 | 31 | 2 |
| 2024-01-03 | 321 | 3 |
| 2024-01-05 | 412 | 4 |
| 2024-01-07 | 93 | 5 |
| 2024-01-07 | 169 | 6 |

I can solve this problem by calculating the average reply time *each day* and then calculating the average reply time over the previous *n* number of days from that, but this doesn't take into account the number of observations each day, which will skew the results if there are outliers for certain days. I want to account for the number of observations when I'm averaging to prevent outliers from throwing off the data.

Here I'm using the package `runner` to get the average reply time *each day* and calculating a moving average from that.

```
daily_reply_time <- df_replies %>%
  filter(!is.na(reply_time) & !is.na(dates)) %>%
  group_by(dates) %>%
  reframe(avg_reply_time = mean(reply_time, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(
    x = "x",
    dates = lubridate::ymd(dates)
  ) %>%
  filter(!is.na(dates)) %>%
  complete(
    nesting(x),
    dates = seq(min(dates), max(dates), by = "day")
  ) %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  arrange(dates) %>%
  mutate(
    dates= lubridate::ymd(dates),
    avg_reply_time = ifelse(is.na(avg_reply_time), 0, as.numeric(avg_reply_time )),
    running_reply_time_30_days = runner::mean_run(x = avg_reply_time, k = 30, idx = dates)
  ) %>%
  select(-x)
```

I create a dummy variable `x` so that nesting works properly; I assume there's a way to skip over that I'm unaware of. Anyways, this would give me averages of 186, 321, 0, 412, 0, and 131 for each *day*, so when I use `runner`, I get a moving average of 175 on 2024-01-08, instead of the 227.83 that is expected when you just sum up all the numbers and divide by the number of observations.

If I skip grouping by each date and instead use the `complete` function, I get an error saying that "'from' must be a finite number." And not using `complete` and trying to use the `runner` package does not throw an error, but averages over the previous *n* rows in the dataset instead of the number of dates.

```
daily_reply_time <- df_replies %>%
  filter(created_at > '2023-12-31') %>%
  mutate(
    created_at = substr(created_at, 1, 10),
    first_reply_time_in_minutes = first_reply_time_in_minutes / 60
  ) %>%
  filter(!is.na(created_at) & !is.na(first_reply_time_in_minutes)) %>%
  mutate(x = "x") %>%
  complete( 
    nesting(x),
    created_at = seq(min(created_at), max(created_at), by = "day")
  )
```

Is there a way to account for the number of observations when calculating running amounts using `runner`, or through some other package?

EDIT: The expected output would contain one row for each date, and a moving average reply time over the previous *n* days, meaning the input and output would have different lengths (amounts are not supposed to match up with the table above, just an example of the expected output given a particular dataframe).

| Dates | Moving Avg. Reply Time |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-01-02 | 125 |
| 2024-01-03 | 108.3 |
| 2024-01-04 | 108.3 |
| 2024-01-05 | 137 |
| 2024-01-06 | 67 |
| 2024-01-07 | 251 |

Comment: Please show the resulting the data frame  that you want corresponding to the input shown assuming 2 days, say.  Also clarify that if the output should be the same number of rows as the input and if so are all days equal to the current date within n days included in previous?, only rows up to the current row? only the n dates strictly less than the current date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it I would use the `roll...` functions from the `{zoo}` package.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
```

First let’s generate some data. each day in january will be present at least once.

```r
set.seed(123)
january_dates <- seq(as.Date("2024-01-01"), length.out = 31, by = "day")
duplicate_dates <- sample(
  x = seq(as.Date("2024-01-01"), length.out = 31, by = "day"),
  size = 29,
  replace = TRUE
)

data <- data.frame(
  ticket_id = 1:60,
  date = c(january_dates, duplicate_dates),
  reply_time = sample(1:300, size = 60, replace = TRUE)
)

head(data)
#>   ticket_id       date reply_time
#> 1         1 2024-01-01        137
#> 2         2 2024-01-02        254
#> 3         3 2024-01-03        211
#> 4         4 2024-01-04         78
#> 5         5 2024-01-05         81
#> 6         6 2024-01-06         43
```

Now let’s calculate the `total_reply_time` and the `number_of_tickets` by day.

```r
summary <- data |>
  arrange(date) |>
  summarise(
    total_reply_time = sum(reply_time),
    number_of_tickets = n(),
    .by = date
  )
```

The last step is to get the weighted rolling average

```r
summary |>
  mutate(
    rollsum_reply_time = zoo::rollsum(total_reply_time, k = 7, fill = NA, align = "right"),
    rollsum_tickerts = zoo::rollsum(number_of_tickets, k = 7, fill = NA, align = "right"),
    rolling_average = rollsum_reply_time / rollsum_tickerts
  )
#>          date total_reply_time number_of_tickets rollsum_reply_time
#> 1  2024-01-01              137                 1                 NA
#> 2  2024-01-02              254                 1                 NA
#> 3  2024-01-03              521                 3                 NA
#> 4  2024-01-04               78                 1                 NA
#> 5  2024-01-05              380                 3                 NA
#> 6  2024-01-06               43                 1                 NA
#> 7  2024-01-07              279                 2               1692
#> 8  2024-01-08              117                 2               1672
#> 9  2024-01-09              308                 2               1726
#> 10 2024-01-10              554                 3               1759
#> 11 2024-01-11               27                 2               1708
#> 12 2024-01-12              135                 1               1463
#> 13 2024-01-13              224                 1               1644
#> 14 2024-01-14              448                 3               1813
#> 15 2024-01-15              452                 2               2148
#> 16 2024-01-16              290                 1               2130
#> 17 2024-01-17               69                 1               1645
#> 18 2024-01-18              281                 2               1899
#> 19 2024-01-19              321                 3               2085
#> 20 2024-01-20              132                 2               1993
#> 21 2024-01-21              141                 1               1686
#> 22 2024-01-22              522                 3               1756
#> 23 2024-01-23              153                 1               1619
#> 24 2024-01-24              294                 1               1844
#> 25 2024-01-25              540                 4               2103
#> 26 2024-01-26              231                 3               2013
#> 27 2024-01-27              502                 3               2383
#> 28 2024-01-28              381                 2               2623
#> 29 2024-01-29               83                 2               2184
#> 30 2024-01-30              116                 1               2147
#> 31 2024-01-31              356                 2               2209
#>    rollsum_tickerts rolling_average
#> 1                NA              NA
#> 2                NA              NA
#> 3                NA              NA
#> 4                NA              NA
#> 5                NA              NA
#> 6                NA              NA
#> 7                12        141.0000
#> 8                13        128.6154
#> 9                14        123.2857
#> 10               14        125.6429
#> 11               15        113.8667
#> 12               13        112.5385
#> 13               13        126.4615
#> 14               14        129.5000
#> 15               14        153.4286
#> 16               13        163.8462
#> 17               11        149.5455
#> 18               11        172.6364
#> 19               13        160.3846
#> 20               14        142.3571
#> 21               12        140.5000
#> 22               13        135.0769
#> 23               13        124.5385
#> 24               13        141.8462
#> 25               15        140.2000
#> 26               15        134.2000
#> 27               16        148.9375
#> 28               17        154.2941
#> 29               16        136.5000
#> 30               16        134.1875
#> 31               17        129.9412
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Let me know if this is what you're looking for. I'm not 100% sure I understanded the question. Sometimes is a good idea to add the expected results in your post.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! I tried to do something similar using `runner`, but I didn't group by date to get the total number of tickets and reply time each day, which is what was giving me problems.

Comment: I would but you need at least 15 rep points to upvote so you'll have to settle for my thanks.

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer. But that's ok, don't worry.